# Ignore Mongoose schema on read only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection where the data conforms to one of a few different schemas. The reason these are in one collection is that I need to be able to query them all together, taking advantage of the schema-less nature of MongoDB.

Is there a way to query a collection with mongoose while ignoring the schema? As an example:

```
var adam = new ContractCustomer({
  // Contract customer data saved to customers collection
})

var betty = new PaygCustomer({
  // PAYG customer data saved to customers collection
})

adam.save()
betty.save()

Customers.find({}).exec().then() // Query all the customers regardless of which schema they belong to.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommand to connect to the database using [mongodb-driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/), and to make a `find` from there. In my knowledge,there is no way to perform a schemaless query using mongoose.

The whole point of mongoose is to use schemas.

(keep your connection to mongoose, just open a parallel connection)